# Magento 2.1: Custom Shipping method - Need to access Region name in `collectRates` method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento-2.1

I am creating a custom shipping method by following [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/). Now I want to access the region name in the `collectRates` method. I can access the `region_code` if the `State/Province` field is a dropdown, but it isn't the case for all the countries.

I actually want the shipping method to be available to only a certain state. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: that is my question too

Comment: @aligh I couldn't get the region_code if the "State/Province" is not a dropdown. So, I added the "State/Province" for the needed country by directly going to the DB and adding them. The table you'll need is `directory_country_region`. For further details, you can see this (blog post)[http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/31/magento-add-state-country-indian-states/]

Answer (score 0):

PLease try this,

```
$region     = ($request->getDestRegionId() !== null) ? $this->getStateNameByRegionID($request->getDestRegionId()) : $request->getDestRegionCode();

public function getStateNameByRegionID($region_id) {
    return $this->_region->load($region_id)->getName();
}
```

> \Magento\Directory\Model\Region
> add Region dependency class to your class.